# argument of type read: typeof elementref is not assignable to parameter of type property static is missing in type

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I've created custom date filter in ag-angular-grid. This is date filter component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading-overlay',
  template: `
        <div #flatpickrEl class="ag-input-wrapper custom-date-filter" role="presentation">
            <input type='text' data-input />
            <a class='input-button' title='clear' data-clear>
                <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    `,
})

export class CustomDateFilter {
  @ViewChild("flatpickrEl", { read: typeof ElementRef }) flatpickrEl: ElementRef;
.....
}
```

Error is in this place: `{ read: typeof ElementRef }`

Error is:

```
A wrapper around a native element inside a View.

An ElementRef is backed by a render-specific element. In browser, this is usually a DOM element.

argument of type {read: 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean' | 'symbol' | 'undefined' | 'object' | 'function' } is not assignable to parameter of type { read?: any static: boolean; } Property 'static' is missing in type {read: 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean' | 'symbol' | 'undefined' | 'object' | 'function' }
```

Comment: When you remove the { read: typeof ElementRef } what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Angular 8 you need to provide `static` property in the options:

```
@ViewChild("flatpickrEl", { read: typeof ElementRef, static: true | false }) flatpickrEl: ElementRef;
```